# Do I change the date of my posts when I make an update?

Tags: search-results, dates

For SERP results, is it a good idea to have the modification date shown instead of keeping the creation date? (i.e. making it look like there is fresh content)

I tend to make changes to my old posts once in a while and I'm wondering whether I should make sure that the modification date gets shown. Will that help drive more clicks to my website?

Note that I'm more thinking about the date shown near the author name at the top of an article. Dates hidden in the header in meta tags and such are probably never shown in the SERP anyway.

Comment: In terms of CTR, yes you should go with it, people often click on fresh results when they have choice. But In terms of ranking, only changing date doesn't add any value.

Comment: @Goyllo Assuming it gets picked up and used in the SERPs. Otherwise, why bother? I do like created and modified dates, but that is personal. I wonder what the word is today on how these dates are used. I used to know, but today I could not tell you. Cheers!!